# How can I change the direction of my CSS underline transition and make it move from right to left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

I found this css code on internet it creates underline animation effect, i need to reverse it to be right-to-left instead of left to right.

[image]

```
.nav-item a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    &:after {
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform: scaleX(0) translate3d(0,0,0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #6cb2eb;
        -o-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
        opacity: 1;
        content: "";
    }
    &:hover {
        &:after {
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
            -moz-transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to change &:after from scaleX(1) to scaleX(-1) it works as i needed but far from the text.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `transform-origin` from `0 0` to `100% 100%`:

```css
.nav-item a {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.nav-item a:after {
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transform: scaleX(0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6cb2eb;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
}
.nav-item a:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scaleX(1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item">
  <a>test</a>
</div>
```

Note: I converted scss to css and I removed useless vendor-specific properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to float: right .nav-item a::after. It will work

```
.nav-item > a {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item > a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #6cb2eb;
    float: right;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
}
.nav-item > a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Check this fiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/jfgq2kva/6/